# Racket upload zip file with parameters through http-client or post-impure-port

Tags: http, post, racket

I want to upload a zip file to server using http-conn-send! or post-impure-port (or post-pure-port). Here is my code:

```
(define post
  (lambda (url data header)
    (call/input-url url
                    (lambda (url header)
                      (post-impure-port url data header))
                    port->string
                    header)))

;;; header
(define header 
 '("Content-Type: multipart/form-data"))

;;; some parameters
(define param `((resource_name . "google")
                (version_name . "5.2")
                (inner_version . "2.0")
                (type . "GAME")
                (sdk_id . "AndGoogle")
                (for_platform . "Android")
                (update_log . "test")))

(define data 
 (bytes-append
  (string->bytes/utf-8 
  (alist->form-urlencoded param))
  #"&file="
  (file->bytes "file.zip")))

(post url data header)
```

but th output is error, can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

**SERVER RESPONSE**

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1

X-Application-Context: application:production

Content-Length: 0

Date: Sat, 09 Jan 2016 01:53:29 GMT

Connection: close

I want to know whether I should add some code like this, though it doesn't work too:

```
(define CRLF "\r\n")
(define boundary "-------------------------RacketFormBoundaryf1nfLeDGcfc30oHf")

(define upload-file (file->bytes "AndGoogle.zip"))

(define data
  (bytes-append
   (->bytes (string-append
             "--" boundary CRLF
             "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"resource_name\"" CRLF
             "AndGoogle" CRLF
             "--" boundary CRLF
             "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"version_name\"" CRLF
             "5.2" CRLF
             "--" boundary CRLF
             "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"AndGoogle.zip\"" CRLF
             "Content-Type: application/zip" CRLF))
   upload-file
   (->bytes (string-append CRLF "--" boundary "--" CRLF))))

(define header
  (list (string-append "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=" boundary)
        (string-append "Content-Length: " (number->string (bytes-length data)))))

(post url data header)
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the error message that you get when you run this?

Comment: @AsumuTakikawa Sorry, I have no error messages on hand. I remember that the error is something like "http/1.1 code:500, server internal error".

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do this after get help from racket user group on google, just add tow CRLF to sub header in form. As follows:

```
(define data
  (bytes-append
   (->bytes (string-append
             "--" boundary CRLF
             "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"resource_name\"" CRLF
             CRLF
             "AndGoogle" CRLF
             "--" boundary CRLF
             "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"version_name\"" CRLF
             CRLF
             "5.2" CRLF
             "--" boundary CRLF
             "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"AndGoogle.zip\"" CRLF
             "Content-Type: application/zip" CRLF 
             CRLF))
   upload-file
   (->bytes (string-append CRLF "--" boundary "--" CRLF))))
```